# Remove a sub-domain from plesk without removing the physical files

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

I have a W2008 server - running Plesk 11 - unusual I know, but I needed some .net as well as some php sites.

Anyway, I'd setup a sub-domain of my main website - and installed Wordpress on it - to build a new site for a site I already hosted.

I set the subdomain to :  http://wptest.mysite.com - and it pointed to a directory under my site root/wptest

Now that my client has approved the WP website under that domain - I want to repoint their existing domain to that same directory.  I know I can do that.

To keep things clean however, I would really like to rename the file folder under my main domain to my clients domain name - and delete the sub-domain - to avoid any confusion later.

If I delete the sub-domain in Plesk - will it also delete the files within the directory it is pointing to?

Can I simply rename the folder (within Windows Explorer) and repoint my domain to that, and delete the subdomain from within plesk, without deleting my website?

Thanks for any advice.

Mark

Comment: You will have to change all of the wordpress permalinks in the database

Comment: Hi - I've no problem changing the permalinks - but will removing the sub-domain delete the files - or am I best leaving the sub-domain as it is?  Thanks, Mark

Comment: Just test it with some another sub-domain.

Answer (score 1):

It will delete your entire site if you delete the subdomain or change the name. This just happened to me this week. I had no idea it was because of wordpress.